# Boolean values in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a method that has a boolean value as a parameter. I'm aware it's better to avoid boolean values. Anyway in my case it's most efficient way.

Well, here is a method:

```
  def some_method(include_some_values = false)
          #do some workcountries = []
          if include_some_values 
             #do some additional work  
           end
           #return value
    end
```

calling (haml)

```
= form_for @address do |f|
  = f.select :fied1, MyModel.some_method(true) #it's okay
```

However if I call it as

```
= f.select :fied1, MyModel.some_method true
```

or

```
= f.select :fied1, MyModel.some_method :true
```

or

```
= f.select :fied1, MyModel.some_method false
```

or

```
= f.select :fied1, MyModel.some_method :false
```

then it's not going to work. Why?

Comment: Why is it "better to avoid boolean values"?

Comment: For clarification, you mean it works as expected with parentheses, but not without?

Comment: @DavidB: I assume the OP means *boolean parameters*. In that case: because a method should do *one thing*, whereas a method a method that takes a boolean parameter pretty much by definition does *two different (possibly even opposite) things*, depending on the value of the boolean argument.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thank you, I was legitimately confused by that statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably

```
= f.select :fied1, MyModel.some_method true
```

is interpreted as:

```
= f.select(:fied1, MyModel.some_method) true
```

So just use parenthesizes to avoid ambiguity.

PS: `:true` is a symbol, so there's no reason to fiddle with symbols if your dealing with booleans.

Comment: In particular, `:false` is `true`.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag, it's very interesting.

Comment: @AlexMaslakov: It's very simple, really: `false` is **false** (obviously) and `nil` is **false** (makes sense). That's it. *Everything* else is **true**. *Everything*. And I mean *really* everything. For example, `0` is **true**, `''` is **true**, `[]` is **true**, `{}` is **true**, `'false'` is **true**, `'no'` is **true**, `:false` is **true**, `42` is **true**, `Object.new` is **true**. Everything.

Answer (score 4):

If your issue involves problems when not using parentheses, it has nothing to do with booleans and everything to do with the Ruby parser.

Passing a method as a parameter to another method requires parentheses in some cases:

```
def a_method(value)
   puts value
end

def one_argument(value)
   puts value
end

def two_arguments(value1, value2)
   puts value1 + value2
end

# These snippets work fine
one_argument a_method 15
one_argument a_method(15)
two_arguments 999, a_method(15)
# ... etc ...

# This one doesn't
two_arguments 999, a_method 15
```

That last example (which is like what you're doing in your question) is ambiguous to the Ruby parser, so you get an error.